# Django blog post image

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Hello i'm new in Django and i am trying to build my personal blog.
in this blog i want my post to have a field where i can post an image. 
here is my code but when i see my post the picture doesn't show.

**setting.py**
     Django settings for mysite project.

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))



# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i9s&v1wse3w%gxyc&3qyft-a(cz1y6^f9gvy+rxsypnsozmt7d'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'blog',
```

)

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)



ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'



WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'
```

## Database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False
```

## Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
)


MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

#### **models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/img')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)
```

#### **template**

```
   <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="img">
```

when i visit my post details site it only shows the alt = "img"

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):
posts =  Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post':post})
```

Comment: What does it render as HTML exactly (and fully) and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Please paste your view as well

Comment: @KlausD. i expected to render '<img src="/media/img/photo.jpg" alt="img">'  and it rendered '<img src="/media/media/img/aristerienotita-logo.jpg" alt="img">'

Comment: @petkostas i posted the views

Comment: Your output is totally correct, since you specify the upload to be media/img this translates to media/media/img if you want media/img then you need to specify upload to img, since MEDIA_URL is always added

Comment: @petkostas still not working

Comment: Have you setup your working environment to serve asset files (MEDIA and STATIC?) I suppose this is a dev system, if not then follow the Django guidelines: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: @petkostas here are my full settings any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Django by default does not serve static files or media files, this is a task that usually falls to a server, in order to get STATIC or MEDIA files served during development (and that should be only during development) in your `urls.py` file somewhere at the end add the following:

```
# Import settings if not imported
from django.conf import settings
# Import static if not imported
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Django provides full documentation on how to setup your environment and how your files should be served for static and media:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

You have to `fit` `MEDIA_URL` in front of `img src`

Try something like this

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.image.url }}" alt="img">
```

Before this, You have to setup `url` for media in `dev` environment.in `urls.py`

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

In settings

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/`

MEDIA_ROOT = '/path/to/image/'
```

**Update for fix your program**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (
    BASE_DIR,
)


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

In `html`

```
<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ post.image.url }}" alt="img">
```

In `urls.py`

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This will do the trick

Comment: He doesn't have to use {{ MEDIA_URL }}, MEDIA URL is already included when using .url

Comment: then which url serve his media ?\

Comment: MEDIA_URL is auto added when using the .url property
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.url

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it working with your help.
There is no need to use the `{{MEDIA_URL}}`  just use the `.url` in the html.
Thank you again this was my first answer in stackoverflow